# Flattening A Transparent PDF With PHP ImageMagick Produces Negative

Tags: php, ghostscript, imagick

As the title says I am trying to flatten a transparent PDF and save it as a jpg. However I keep getting a negative image. I know I can just do a negative image after I flatten it, but I am more interested in why this is happening in the first place. Below is my code. Thanks in advance for any light you could shine on this.

```
$imagick->readImage($imageFile);
$imagick->setImageBackgroundColor('#FFFFFF');
$imagick->setImage($imagick->mergeImageLayers(imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN));
$imagick->setImageFormat("jpg");
$imagick->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$imagick->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
$imagick->writeImage($saveImageAs);
```

EDIT
[Link to file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sedlfinyqziayu8/5_5%20x%204_25%20-%20Grid.pdf?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the version of ghostscript I was using. Upgrading to ghostscript 9.22 resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Imagemagick uses Ghostscript to read PDFs. If the PDF is CMYKA, then Ghostscript does not handle that properly. So convert to RGBA first by adding the equivalent of -colorspace sRGB **before** reading the PDF. If that does not work, then post a link to one of your PDF files that behaves as you have described. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setcolorspace.php

I do not know Imagick well, so I may not have the syntax proper below for the colorspace. So correct my command if needed.

So try something like:

```
$imagick->setColorspace(imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);
$imagick->readImage($imageFile);
$imagick->setImageBackgroundColor('#FFFFFF');
$imagick->setImage($imagick->mergeImageLayers(imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN));
$imagick->setImageFormat("jpg");
$imagick->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$imagick->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
$imagick->writeImage($saveImageAs);
```

I assume you have initialized $imagick using $imagick = new Imagick(); already. If not, then you need to do that.

Here is what I get with your image using Imagemagick 6.9.10.25 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra.

Straight CMYK rasterizing (background alpha is lost and background becomes white):

```
convert 5_5x4_25-Grid.pdf -background skyblue -flatten result1.jpg
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Converting from CMYK to sRGB before rasterizing.

```
convert -colorspace sRGB 5_5x4_25-Grid.pdf -background skyblue -flatten result2.jpg
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Converting from CMYK to sRGB before rasterizing, then converting back to CMYK with -colorspace (colors slightly off).

```
convert -colorspace sRGB 5_5x4_25-Grid.pdf -background skyblue -flatten -colorspace CMYK result3.jpg
```

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Converting from CMYK to sRGB before rasterizing, then converting back to CMYK with -profile (colors better represented):

```
convert -colorspace sRGB 5_5x4_25-Grid.pdf -background skyblue -flatten -profile /Users/fred/images/profiles/USWebCoatedSWOP.icc result4.jpg
```

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Note that Imagemagick using Ghostscript shows no alpha channel for the CMYK PDF.

```
    Image: 5_5x4_25-Grid.pdf
  Format: PDF (Portable Document Format)
  Mime type: application/pdf
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 414x324+0+0
  Resolution: 72x72
  Print size: 5.75x4.5
  Units: Undefined
  Colorspace: CMYK
  Type: ColorSeparation
  Endianess: Undefined
  Depth: 16/8-bit
  Channel depth:
    cyan: 8-bit
    magenta: 8-bit
    yellow: 8-bit
    black: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 134136
    Cyan:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 34695 (0.529412)
      mean: 2051.88 (0.0313097)
      standard deviation: 6698 (0.102205)
      kurtosis: 14.5033
      skewness: 3.89729
      entropy: 0.258857
    Magenta:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 54998 (0.839216)
      mean: 5682.95 (0.0867162)
      standard deviation: 13648.7 (0.208265)
      kurtosis: 2.95123
      skewness: 2.13618
      entropy: 0.258857
    Yellow:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 55255 (0.843137)
      mean: 5710.18 (0.0871318)
      standard deviation: 13735.4 (0.209589)
      kurtosis: 3.0097
      skewness: 2.14687
      entropy: 0.258857
    Black:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 42405 (0.647059)
      mean: 1985.17 (0.0302918)
      standard deviation: 8063.54 (0.123042)
      kurtosis: 16.6119
      skewness: 4.23784
      entropy: 0.258857
```

Comment: You are correct. It is a CMYK-A pdf. This hack seems to do the trick, not sure what effects converting to rgb and back to cmyk will have on my files though. Do you know is this an issue relating to a specific version of Ghostscript? I am using v9.22 and see they are upto v9.26 now. I'm wondering if it's been addressed in the new version.

Comment: If you post an example file and a **Ghostscript** command line I'll be happy to take a look. There is no such colour space in PDF as CMYK-A. You can have CMYK and transparency, which may or may not be limited to an alpha, but the alpha is not specified as part of the colour space. I'm not sure what point fmw42 is trying to make, but Ghostscript should render a CMYK PDF (with or without transparency) correctly to either a CMYK or RGB JPEG file. If it doesn't then that would be a bug. What ImageMagick does with a CMYK JPEG file I suspect may be the problem.

Comment: Correct colorspace is just CMYK, but it contains an alpha channel. I created the pdf test image with Illustrator and it's literally just a few black and red stroked lines saved with the high print quality settings. I seem to be able to open both RGB and CMYK jpg's and save them without issue. However they do have the icc profiles embedded. I'm wondering if the PDF does not.

Comment: I have edited the original post to include a link to the PDF file I am testing with.

Comment: See my examples in my post above.

Comment: `KenS` My point was that to my knowledge, Imagemagick using Ghostscript will not keep the alpha channel in a CMYK PDF when rendering. The recommended advise is to convert the CMYK with alpha channel to RGB with alpha channel before rasterizing the PDF using -colorspace sRGB. If this behavior is no longer true, then please correct me and I will approach the Imagemagick developers to see how the delegate.xml file needs to be changed. The issue is not GS version related as far as I know. My apologies for my sloppy terminology. When I said CMYKA, I meant CMYK color space with alpha channel.

Comment: `KenS`. Is there a particular sDEVICE needed to properly render CMYK with alpha PDF using Ghostscript?

Comment: I do not get the same results that you show in your first example using the command line. Again I get a negative image using ImageMagick 6.9.9-39 Q16 x86_64. I'll have to try and update ImageMagick

Comment: I just noticed in the file info of the converted image the Image Type is listed as ColorSeperation. Would this cause the negative result? If so why is it defaulting to this?

Comment: Upgrading to imageMagick 7.0.8-25 did not resolve the issue

Comment: I believe that color separation means CMYK. Some viewers do not handle CMYK (without profile) very well and show it as its negative. It is viewer dependent. Some work fine. Try my commands in the command line rather than Imagick. Does that work the same as my results? The best solution I know is to convert to sRGB as I explained above. That will ensure you get the proper  looking result. You can also then convert back to CMYK if needed, but use a profile. Then the different viewers can use the profile to show it correctly.